# Visibility of ImageButton in MVVMCross

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have the following `axml` where I have two image buttons, but I only want to show one at a time and implement something toggle feature.

More specifically, when a user clicks on `button1`, it will hide `button1` and will show `button2` and vice versa. I am using `MVVMCross` pattern.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/myBtn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/myBtn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_white" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use the [Visibility Plugin](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Value-Converters#the-mvx-visibility-valueconverters) (add it from NuGet)

Then add: a bool property and a command to switch the bool in the ViewModel:

```cs
private bool _boolInViewModel; 
public bool BoolInViewModel
{
    get { return _boolInViewModel; }
    set { _boolInViewModel = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => BoolInViewModel);}
}

public IMvxCommand CommandToSwitchBool
{
    get
    {
        return new MvxCommand(()=>
            {
                BoolInViewModel = !BoolInViewModel;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

and then Bind to to the bool with the visibility converter and inverted visibility convert and the command to the click event on the buttons like so:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/myBtn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back"
            app:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(BoolInViewModel); Click CommandToSwitchBool"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/myBtn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_white"
            app:MvxBind="Visibility InvertedVisibility(BoolInViewModel); Click CommandToSwitchBool"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked flawlessly. Good to know `InvertedVisibility` feature!

Comment: Yeah there is lots of cool things it can do too, like binding visibility to a count on a list to show/hide "no items in list" views.  Credit really goes to the guys making the plugin here https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Plugins/tree/master/Visibility

Comment: @IainSmith I know this is old but could you include relevant namespace aliases? (such as 'app') Also, is this a shared project or a platform view? Lastly, why does InvertedVisibility not require a namespace and where does that plugin need to be loaded/registered/declared? Tried finding this information in the docs and sample projects with little success.
Docs: https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/value-converters?#the-mvx-visibility-valueconverters 
Sample: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/tree/master/ValueConversion

Comment: I have updated with where you *could* put the app namespace as an example but I am using the XAML that @casillas used in his question to help give a solution to his problem. You will need the Nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.Plugin.Visibility and here is an example of how to use it https://github.com/b099l3/StackOverflow/tree/master/ExampleOfMvxVisibility If this doesnt help I would suggest writing another question